# Part of POST Data missing while sending data from AS3 to PHP

Tags: php, actionscript-3, flash

I am sending some data from AS3 to PHP using the Greensock DataLoader. Here is my code:

```
var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest(PHP_LOCATION);
var data:URLVariables = new URLVariables();
data.abc = "abc";
data.pqr = voicedata;
data.def = 1;
data.xyz = "xyz";
data.lmn = "";
request.data = data;
request.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;

var dataLoader:DataLoader = new DataLoader(request, { name:"phploader", onProgress:OnProgressHandler, onComplete:OnCompleteHandler, onError:OnErrorHandler } );
dataLoader.load();
```

So I am sending some normal data like string and int with **voice bytearray**. On PHP I am receiving the data as:

```
$abc = $_POST['abc'];
$def = $_POST['def'];
$pqr = $_POST['pqr'];
$xyz = $_POST['xyz'];
$lmn = $_POST['lmn'];
SomePHPFunction($abc, $def, $pqr, $xyz, $lmn);
```

Most of the times, the functionality i.e. the communication between AS3 and PHP is working fine. However, what happens is, sometimes (5 out of 20 times) the PHP function encounters an error. The error I get for these 5 times on PHP is:

```
PHP Notice:  Undefined index: abc
PHP Notice:  Undefined index: lmn
```

Any particular reason why this is happening? I am clueless on why part of the data is being received, but part of it is not.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
import flash.display.*;
import flash.events.*;
import flash.net.URLLoader;
import flash.net.URLRequest;
import flash.net.URLVariables;
import flash.net.URLLoaderDataFormat;
import flash.net.URLRequestMethod;

    var urlReq:URLRequest = new URLRequest ("nameofphppage.php");

    urlReq.method = URLRequestMethod.POST; 

    var urlVars:URLVariables = new URLVariables(); 
    urlVars.abc = 'abc';
    urlVars.def = 'def';
    urlVars.pqr = 'pqr';
    urlVars.xyz = 'xyz';
    urlVars.lmn = 'lmn';

    urlReq.data = urlVars;  

    var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader (urlReq); 

    loader.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.VARIABLES; 
    loader.load(urlReq);
```

and then for your php

```
<?php
$abc = $_POST['abc'];
$def = $_POST['def'];
$pqr = $_POST['pqr'];
$xyz = $_POST['xyz'];
$lmn = $_POST['lmn'];
SomePHPFunction($abc, $def, $pqr, $xyz, $lmn);
?>
```

Comment: Was using the traditional approach of URLLoader. However, I found the current approach of using Greensock's DataLoader more reliable as compared to URLLoader. And it has been working fine. So I dont really find a need to change that approach unless this problem is specifically happening because of that.